# Android Open GLES fragment shader error

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, fragment-shader

I have a monochrome.vs which is

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_textCoord0;
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_textCoords;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

void main(){
   v_color = a_color;
   v_textCoords = a_textCoord0;
   gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
}
```

I have a fragment shader  monochrome.fs

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform float u_amount;


void main(){
   vec4 color = v_color* texture(u_texture,v_texCoords);
   float greyScale = dot(color.rgb,vec3(0.222,0.707,0.071));
   color.rgb = mix(color.rgb,vec3(greyScale));
   gl_FragColor =color;
}
```

I am running this through libGDX on an android device.

I am using the code

```
if(!shaderProgram.isCompiled()){
        String msg = "shader not compiled ->"+shaderProgram.getLog();
        throw new GdxRuntimeException(msg);
    }
```

which is producing the following output

```
10-23 11:21:49.546 4979-5018/? E/AndroidRuntime: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: shader not compiled ->Fragment shader compilation failed.
10-23 11:21:49.546 4979-5018/? E/AndroidRuntime: ERROR: 0:5: 'varying' : Syntax error:  syntax error
10-23 11:21:49.546 4979-5018/? E/AndroidRuntime: ERROR: 1 compilation errors.  No code generated.
```

I really cant see what I am doing wrong, nor can I find an answers on SO, any help?

Comment: You forgot a semicolon after `precision mediump float`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the semicolon, so I changed

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float
#endif
```

to

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform float u_amount;


void main(){
  vec4 color = v_color* texture2D(u_texture,v_texCoords);
  float greyScale = dot(color.rgb,vec3(0.222,0.707,0.071));
  color.rgb = mix(color.rgb,vec3(greyScale),u_amount);
  gl_FragColor =color;
}
```

and it now works